# Python: How do I get an if statement to check if a condition is true at the end of a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Specifically, I'm doing the hangman challenge from the 100 days of coding by UDEMY.  I can't seem to figure out how to check if the user has lost by reaching "0" of "6" lives.  When I use this code, it subtracts 1 from "lives" during every instance in the for loop that doesn't match the guess:

```
    lives = 6    
    while not end_of_game:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    for position in range(word_length):
        letter = chosen_word[position]
        if letter == guess:
            display[position] = letter
        elif letter != guess:
            lives -= 1
            if lives == 0:
                end_of_game = True
    print(f"{' '.join(display)}")
```

Comment: Always tag your questions with the appropriate language. That will ensure they get the maximum number of viewers.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some bench checking of your code.  After straightening out the indentation, the main problem I spot in your code is that even if a guessed letter is found and you update the display position, your "for" loop keeps checking the guessed letter against the remaining letters in your word.  And that then decrements the life count even when there is a good guess.

I would think that you would want your code to more closely resemble the following code snippet:

```
lives = 6    
while not end_of_game:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    found_letter = False                      # Additional test variable
    for position in range(word_length):
        letter = chosen_word[position]
        if letter == guess:
            display[position] = letter
            found_letter = True
    if found_letter == False:          # Do the test for good/bad guess here
        lives -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            end_of_game = True
            break
    print(f"{' '.join(display)}")
```

The additional true/false variable "found_letter" would dictate whether or not the life count should be decremented and the test would occur once the whole word has been checked for the guessed letter.

Give that a try.